# ionic custom directive not working in emulator

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an application in Ionic 1 that uses custom directives. These work when testing in the browser, but do not show up in the emulator or on the iphone. I have seen that this has been an issue for others, but none of the suggestions have worked for me. Are there any suggestions out there for how to make a custom directive appear in the emulator (or, more importantly, on the iphone)?

Here is what I have tried. None of this has worked.

1. Moving the directives and controllers into the same file
2. Changing element directives to attribute directives (i.e `<div my-directive></div>` instead of `<my-directive></my-directive>`
3. Adding the CSS `display: block` to my element directives
4. Adding `<ion-view><ion-content>` tags around the directives, both within the directive templates, and then outside of the templates around the directives themselves in the parent templates.

[Link to my project on github](https://github.com/galencorey/GameOfLife)

And here are the essential pieces of code:

**Directives**

```
angular.module('starter.directives', [])
.directive('grid', function(GridFactory){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: '/templates/grid.html',
    link: function(scope){
      //does stuff 
    } 
  }
})
.directive('cell', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: '/templates/cell.html',
    scope: {
      marker: '=',
      isAlive: '=',
      cellClick: '&'
    }
  }
})
```

**Directive Templates**

*grid*

```
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in grid" style="height: 5vw" >
    <div class="col gc-border gc-no-padding" ng-repeat="cell in row">
      <cell is-alive=isAlive(cell.marker) marker=cell.marker neighbors = cell.neighbors cell-click=cellClick(cell)></cell>
    </div>
  </div>
```

*cell*

*parent template*

```
<ion-view view-title="Play">
  <ion-content>
   <div class="card">
    <p>It rebuilt 2!</p>
     <grid></grid>
   </div>
  <div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-calm" on-tap="step()">Step</a>
    <a class="button button-calm" on-tap="play()">{{isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play" }}</a>
    <a class="button button-calm" on-tap="clear()">Clear</a>
  </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: can you please add your code here so that we can be specific instead of looking the **entire code**??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the templateUrl in your directives you have the following:

```
  .directive('grid', function(GridFactory){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/templates/grid.html',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.grid = GridFactory.makeGrid(20,20);
      scope.alive = [];
   ...
```

Remove the forward slash:

`templateUrl: '/templates/grid.html',`  to

`templateUrl: 'templates/grid.html',` and for the rest of the `templateUrl`'s.